# See output of UNIX mail in console

Tags: bash, email, unix, sendmail, mailx

I am running mail with the -v flag. The status report is being mailed: `Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <me>.` I would like to see what's happening in the console, as it's happening.

Is it possible to display the log/status report for mail in real time rather than mailing it after it's completed?

Comment: Which version of `mail` are you using? Are you running an interactive shell? I've just tried it and the results were displayed in the terminal as you're looking for.

Comment: Also which MTA do you have installed?

Comment: Mail version 8.1 6/6/93. Postfix. Also, I'm on OSX. Probably should have mentioned that. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible with Postfix. Its replacement for `sendmail` sends the delivery status report, rather than shows it on the console (despite the man page claiming otherwise): http://oss.org.cn/man/newsoft/postfix/DEBUG_README.html#trace_mail